# Java: Adding a User Interface to a program

Tags: java, user-interface

If I have Java program and I need to alter it to an interface and include icons, 
is there any easy I can do this and is there a good application that can help me to do it ?
or do I have to code it in myself?

Comment: Someone removed the word "Website" is that an edit by the original poster?

Comment: @Quarrelsome: after reading the OP's post a few times, I concluded that he's looking for a website that might have a solution to his problem. Thus, website does not seem to be needed there.

Answer (score 5):

Nop, /me thinks ur need 1337 mad Java programin' skillz!

Translation for the rest of the world: Sorry, you'll need to program in Java.

**Added:** Hey, what's with the downvotes? He started it! :P Besides - no matter if he wants to add or modify (the original text wasn't clear on this) the UI of a Java program, he **will** need to program in Java to bring his UI together with the code. There is no miracle tool that can allow you to draw an UI and it will suddenly do what you do.

Comment: +1; this will definitely need at least some code to be written.

Comment: +1; you really ought to know how to code teh Java. Once you can do that there's not much point in using GUI builders. It's not like you have to do absolute positioning these days.

Answer (score 2):

[Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) has a [Swing GUI Builder](http://www.netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html). Quoting from their website. Let's hope this doesn't count has hidden advertising :)

> Design Swing GUIs by dragging and
>   positioning GUI components from a
>   palette onto a canvas. The GUI builder
>   automatically takes care of the
>   correct spacing and alignment. Click
>   into JLabels, JButtons, ButtonGroups,
>   JTrees, JTextFields, ComboBoxes and
>   edit their properties directly in
>   place. You can use the GUI builder to
>   prototype GUIs right in front of
>   customers.

Comment: Netbeans works pretty well if you start with a netbeans project!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a UI to your Java program there are tools to help you, such as the [Swing GUI Builder](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gui_builder.html) inside of IntelliJ Idea.  However, you're still going to have to write the appropriate code to hook into the UI.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a website? Well depending on whether it uses CSS you *might* be able to just modify a .css file. This will only let you modify how the site *looks* as opposed to *works*.

See [here](http://www.csszengarden.com/) for an example of how this technology works. However this depends on how css-dependent the website is and it's possible you may still run into some difficulties.

Comment: thanks for the downvote, try checking the comment on the OP or the history of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a Java framework to help you with the UI. For example, you can use JSF (Javaserver faces), which allows you to drag and drop components for a UI onto the site. Otherwise, you can use web programs such as Dreamweaver to design the UI, before coding the backend logic yourself in java.